# Find the sum of profit since last transaction(same day or a previous day) at the end of a day in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, common-table-expression

I had asked [a question in April](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791893/sql-query-to-find-the-sum-of-all-rows-and-sum-of-portions-of-rows-within-a-group) and [@Mikael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/569436/mikael-eriksson) helped me solve it. The requirement has since changed and I am having trouble figuring it out how to build the query.
The table structure is

```
SID Sdate                  Profit   Units 
1   7/26/2010 9:15:00 AM    -37.5   -1      
1   7/26/2010 12:00:00 PM   -125    -1      
1   7/26/2010 12:45:01 PM   -12.5   -1      
1   7/26/2010 12:45:02 PM   0       0       
1   7/26/2010 12:45:03 PM   -75     1       
1   7/26/2010 2:00:01 PM    -12.5   1       
1   7/26/2010 2:00:02 PM    0       0       
1   7/26/2010 2:00:03 PM    -125    -1      
1   7/26/2010 2:15:00 PM    -50     -1  
1   7/27/2010 9:15:00 AM    25      -1      
1   7/27/2010 12:00:00 PM   196     -1      
1   7/27/2010 2:15:00 PM    -12.5   -1 
1   7/28/2010 9:15:00 AM    425     -1      
1   7/28/2010 12:00:00 PM   -125    -1      
1   7/28/2010 2:15:00 PM    -12.5   -1 
1   7/29/2010 9:15:00 AM    -37.5   -1      
1   7/29/2010 12:00:00 PM   -90     -1      
1   7/29/2010 12:45:01 PM   -12.5   -1      
1   7/29/2010 12:45:02 PM   0       0       
1   7/29/2010 12:45:03 PM   -75     1       
1   7/29/2010 2:15:00 PM    23      1
```

The calculation is explained as :

```
SID Sdate                  Profit   Units   End-of-day-Profit   Comments
1   7/26/2010 9:15:00 AM    -37.5   -1      
1   7/26/2010 12:00:00 PM   -125    -1      
1   7/26/2010 12:45:01 PM   -12.5   -1      
1   7/26/2010 12:45:02 PM   0       0       
1   7/26/2010 12:45:03 PM   -75     1       
1   7/26/2010 2:00:01 PM    -12.5   1       
1   7/26/2010 2:00:02 PM    0       0       
1   7/26/2010 2:00:03 PM    -125    -1      
1   7/26/2010 2:15:00 PM    -50     -1  -175    SUM of profit(row 9 to row 11) going back to 7/26/2010  2:00:02 PM
1   7/27/2010 9:15:00 AM    25      -1      
1   7/27/2010 12:00:00 PM   196     -1      
1   7/27/2010 2:15:00 PM    -12.5   -1  33.5    SUM of profit ( row 9 to row 14) going back to 7/26/2010  2:00:02 PM
1   7/28/2010 9:15:00 AM    425     -1      
1   7/28/2010 12:00:00 PM   -125    -1      
1   7/28/2010 2:15:00 PM    -12.5   -1  321     SUM of profit(row9 to row 17) going back to 7/26/2010  2:00:02 PM
1   7/29/2010 9:15:00 AM    -37.5   -1      
1   7/29/2010 12:00:00 PM   -90     -1      
1   7/29/2010 12:45:01 PM   -12.5   -1      
1   7/29/2010 12:45:02 PM   0       0       
1   7/29/2010 12:45:03 PM   -75     1       
1   7/29/2010 2:15:00 PM    23      1   -52     SUM of profit(row 22 to row 23) going back to 7/29/2010  12:45:02 PM
```

The result would be

```
SID Sdate       Profit   Units
1   7/26/2010   -175    -1
1   7/27/2010   33.5    -1
1   7/28/2010   321     -1
1   7/29/2010   -52     1
```

The sum of net profit column is taken at 2:15PM everyday for every SID. I included one SID for simplicity.The idea is to look back either current day or previous days for the row that has profit=0 and units=0. Once that row is found, then sum all profit values.

I appreciate any help on this.Thanks.

Comment: `The sum of net profit column is taken at 2:15PM everyday` – how? I mean, is it (supposed to be) done manually or using an Agent job? In your example there's a row at 2:15 PM every day, which contains a Profit value too. What if there wasn't such a row? Should it, for the sake of adding another End-of-day-Profit value, be inserted with the time of 2:15PM and the Profit of 0, or should the script just search the latest row with a Profit and store the End-of-day-Profit there?

Comment: Is Sdate a column with a unique constraint? And how is the data inserted? Do you first insert a record with Sdate M/dd/yyyy 2:15:00 PM and after that calculate the End-Of-Day-Profit?

Comment: @Frans, sdate is not a column with a unique constraint. the end of day record indicated by m/dd/yyyy 2:15PM is stored in the table when a process is run to generate these records.

Comment: @Andriy M , there is a row for 2:15PM stored in the table(by a process executed previously) that stores the profit value for end of day. the row at 2:15 indicates its the row for end of day.

Comment: Thank you, almost everything's clear by now. You've added a sample output. So the query you are looking for shouldn't update the End-of-day-Profit column but rather return a rowset with the calculated value, right? It's a bit confusing that your output contains more than one row, while previously you said that the query is supposed to calculate the sum starting from the latest (0, 0) row (so it would be one value). Another confusing thing is, your output also includes values of Units. You never say in your question how they should be calculated. Please clarify how it should be.

Comment: 1. The output contains more than one row because the sum of profit is being calculated at the end of each day. So, there is a row for each day from the input table. 

2. The units column in the output is the units value at 2:15PM, for the day the sum of profit is being calculated.
Thanks for responding.

Comment: I made a small change in my query. Checking for second = 0 in 14:15:00, imagine someone makes a line that exact minute. Just to prevent nasty surprises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have access to a database to test it. But populate a table variable @t and try this.

```
declare @t table (SID int, Sdate datetime, profit decimal(9,1), units int)

<populate it>
```

I had guess you want a list for each SID. I misunderstood that. I like to change my answer to this.

```
select SID, Sdata, (select sum(Profit) from @t where Sdate between s.start and s.Sdate and S.SID = SID) profit, Units from 
(select SID, Sdata, (select max(Sdata) from @t where profit = 0 and unit = 0 and Sdata < t.Sdate and SID = t.SID) start from @t t 
where DATEPART(MINUTE, t.Sdata) =15 AND DATEPART(HOUR, t.Sdata) = 14 AND DATEPART(SECOND, t.Sdata) = 0 ) s
ORDER BY SID, Sdate
```

Comment: your query produces the required results. Before I declare it as an answer, I want to double check the results for more than just this one SID. Thanks very much for responding.

Comment: I just finished verifying the results. The query works fine. Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

DDL & sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE atable (
  SID int,
  Sdate datetime,
  Profit money,
  Units int
);
INSERT INTO atable (SID, Sdate, Profit, Units)
SELECT 1, '7/26/2010 9:15:00 AM' , -37.5, -1   UNION ALL    
SELECT 1, '7/26/2010 12:00:00 PM', -125 , -1   UNION ALL    
SELECT 1, '7/26/2010 12:45:01 PM', -12.5, -1   UNION ALL    
SELECT 1, '7/26/2010 12:45:02 PM', 0    ,  0   UNION ALL     
SELECT 1, '7/26/2010 12:45:03 PM', -75  ,  1   UNION ALL     
SELECT 1, '7/26/2010 2:00:01 PM' , -12.5,  1   UNION ALL     
SELECT 1, '7/26/2010 2:00:02 PM' , 0    ,  0   UNION ALL     
SELECT 1, '7/26/2010 2:00:03 PM' , -125 , -1   UNION ALL    
SELECT 1, '7/26/2010 2:15:00 PM' , -50  , -1   UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '7/27/2010 9:15:00 AM' , 25   , -1   UNION ALL    
SELECT 1, '7/27/2010 12:00:00 PM', 196  , -1   UNION ALL    
SELECT 1, '7/27/2010 2:15:00 PM' , -12.5, -1   UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '7/28/2010 9:15:00 AM' , 425  , -1   UNION ALL    
SELECT 1, '7/28/2010 12:00:00 PM', -125 , -1   UNION ALL    
SELECT 1, '7/28/2010 2:15:00 PM' , -12.5, -1   UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '7/29/2010 9:15:00 AM' , -37.5, -1   UNION ALL    
SELECT 1, '7/29/2010 12:00:00 PM', -90  , -1   UNION ALL    
SELECT 1, '7/29/2010 12:45:01 PM', -12.5, -1   UNION ALL    
SELECT 1, '7/29/2010 12:45:02 PM', 0    ,  0   UNION ALL    
SELECT 1, '7/29/2010 12:45:03 PM', -75  ,  1   UNION ALL    
SELECT 1, '7/29/2010 2:15:00 PM' , 23   ,  1;
```

The query:

```
WITH ranges AS (
  SELECT
    t.SID,
    t.Sdate,
    t.Units,
    SdateStart = MAX(t0.Sdate)
  FROM atable t
    INNER JOIN atable t0
       ON t0.SID = t.SID AND t0.Sdate < t.Sdate
      AND t0.Profit = 0 AND t0.Units = 0
  WHERE DATEPART(HH, t.Sdate) = 14
    AND DATEPART(MI, t.Sdate) = 15
  GROUP BY
    t.SID,
    t.Sdate,
    t.Units
)
SElECT
  r.SID,
  r.Sdate,
  Profit = SUM(t.Profit),
  r.Units
FROM ranges r
  INNER JOIN atable t ON t.SID = r.SID
    AND t.Sdate BETWEEN r.SdateStart AND r.Sdate
GROUP BY
  r.SID,
  r.Sdate,
  r.Units;
```

The output:

```
SID         Sdate                   Profit                Units
----------- ----------------------- --------------------- -----------
1           2010-07-26 14:15:00.000 -175.00               -1
1           2010-07-27 14:15:00.000 33.50                 -1
1           2010-07-28 14:15:00.000 321.00                -1
1           2010-07-29 14:15:00.000 -52.00                1
```

Comment: @Andriy M, I tried to filter the data using the criteria SID=1 inside the "ranges" cte while trying to run this query against the database. Its returning empty results. I am not sure why.

Comment: @Andriy M, never mind. I hadnt refreshed the page. I just ran the revised query. And it executed just fine. Thanks for your help. For what its worth, the cte seems to be running faster than the subquery version. =)

Comment: Isn't the performance difference caused by the sorting in my version ?

Comment: @ARK: I only tested this on the small sample I've borrowed from your question. And I was curious enough as to how well my solution performed compared to the other one. If one is to believe execution plans, then, without any indexing, @t-clausen.dk's solution beat mine considerably. However, making `(SID, Sdate)` the primary key seemed to put the latter on a par with the former. I haven't investigated further, though.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk, you are right. It was the order by clause. I added an index and now its fast. Thanks for clearing that up.